# Pygame - Moving rect between two points

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a rect move between two points in pygame. I've been able to make it move onto another rect and then stop, but then it won't move backwards, like it should.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, so I decided to ask for help. Here's my code:

```
import pygame

width, height = 800, 600
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Test")
gameExit = False
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
block_size = 10


def gameloop():
    lead_x1, lead_x2 = 1, 100
    lead_y1, lead_y2 = 1, 1
    velocity = 0.2
    gameExit = False
    white = (255, 255, 255)
    black = (0, 0, 0)
    red = (255, 0, 0)
    block_size = 10

    while not gameExit:
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [lead_x1, lead_y1, block_size, block_size])
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [lead_x2, lead_y2, block_size, block_size])
        lead_x1 += velocity
        if lead_x1 >= lead_x2:
            lead_x1 += -velocity
        if lead_x1 <= 0:
            lead_x1 += velocity
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
        pygame.display.update()
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
gameloop()
```

Comment: Basically you want that when two rectangles collide, they should move in opposite direction after that ?

Comment: Yes -  I want a rect that, when colliiding with another rect, moves the opposite direction.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to place line `lead_x1 += velocity` inside the else statement, something like this:-

```
import pygame

width, height = 800, 600
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Test")
gameExit = False
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
block_size = 10


def gameloop():
    lead_x1, lead_x2 = 1, 100
    lead_y1, lead_y2 = 1, 1
    velocity = 0.2
    gameExit = False
    white = (255, 255, 255)
    black = (0, 0, 0)
    red = (255, 0, 0)
    block_size = 10
    toogle_flag = 1
    while not gameExit:
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [lead_x1, lead_y1, block_size, block_size])
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [lead_x2, lead_y2, block_size, block_size])
        lead_x1 += toggle_flag * velocity
        if lead_x1 >= lead_x2:
            toggle_flag = -1*toggle_flag
        if lead_x1 <= 0:
            toggle_flag = -1*toggle_flag
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
        pygame.display.update()
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
gameloop()
```

So what I am doing here is, let's take take a flag called `toggle_flag`, initialize it to `1`.

1. Out box is at position 1, we add `toggle_flag * velocity` to our `lead_x1`. i.e we are basically adding `velocity`.
2. Once we touch the second box, we flip the value of `toggle_flag` to `-1`.
   What will happen is, we keep on adding `-velocity` to our `lead_x1`.
3. Now, once we reach `0`. We again flip the value of `toggle_flag` by multiplying it by `-1`, which we get us to add `velocity` to out `lead_x1`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It didn't fix my problem, but thank you for the help nonetheless!

Comment: Can you tell me the behavior after running my code ?

Comment: Of course! It smoothly runs to the block, and begins to move to the other way but stops.
Like it moves inches back and forth, it doesn't run the whole way back.
Like it's trembling.

Comment: I have made updates to the code, try it now and let me know the behavior. Actually I don't have pygame installed on my system, so I will be asking you to run the code few times, but don't worry we will get to the solution.

Comment: It works now, but I don't understand what you did! Would you care to explain, please?

Comment: Let me explain it in the answer, so that for future people also it's understandable.

Comment: Also, you can mark this post as answer, for future references. Let me know if you need more help to understand the logic. Try it out on paper and pen.

Comment: Thanks, helped a lot!

Comment: Wait no, I found another bug! They keep going back and forth but the distance they go to is reduced, until they start going on one way undefinitly

Comment: So block2 will stay static I suppose as you are only changing the x value of block 1 , am I right ?

Comment: Actually, your sample actually works. I just tried adding it to my will be snake game and it got that bug, sorry for the inconvinience.

Comment: ha ha cool, that's what I thought, logic wise doesn't seem anything wrong here, cool glad that my answer works and helped you.